# Ruby on Rails - PayPal doesn't recognize payment URL with different currency (EUR)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'd like to build a PayPal payment URL with EUR currency.

I found a countrycode for Euro (EUR) at:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/

I put that to my URL:

```
  def paypal_url(return_path)
    values = {
        business: "paypal@page.info",
        cmd: "_xclick",
        upload: 1,
        return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
        invoice: id,
        amount: amount, 
        currency: 'EUR',
        item_name: verwendungszweck,
        item_number: id,
        quantity: '1',
        notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
    }
    "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
  end
```

which redirects to:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?
amount=42.0&
business=paypal%40page.info&
cmd=_xclick&
currency=EUR&
invoice=7&
item_name=kostendeckung&
item_number=7&
notify_url=http%3A%2F%2F78.232.186.71%2Fhook&quantity=1
  &return=http%3A%2F%2F78.232.186.71%2Fdonations.7&upload=1
```

but when I fire it up, paypal shows me the price with USD currency.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup currencies that you want to handle in your paypal account.
Check the link https://webinterpret.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203728826-How-do-I-set-up-my-PayPal-to-accept-foreign-currencies-new-PayPal-interface-

Comment: Yes, I've done that before. My currency is "Euro (Standard)", but the payment shows up with USD